# LIBGDX - Different Orthographic camera translation speeds for different phones

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine, frame-rate

**onCreate**

```
cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
```

**onUpdate**

```
cam.translate(0,MyGdxGame.CAMERA_TRANSLATION);
```

The camera translation speed for different phones varies.
What could be the reason? And how to overcome it?

Comment: What exactly is `CAMERA_TRANSLATION`? If it's a constant value and your camera is getting different sizes on different devices like you have now there will be a visual difference. But if you use the delta values in `GestureListener.pan` it should be equal to all devices I think, using a `FitViewport` might also work since each device will show the same amount of game world.

Comment: value of CAMERA_TRANSLATION should be in terms of Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); with delta time.

Comment: Use Viewports (see the libgdx wiki) and translations should always be a speed multiplied by delta time, not a constant displacement.